# Renting AWS Device Farm for testing anti-virus application

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm, malware-detection, antimalware

Can we use **AWS Device Farm** to test anti-virus application by installing real malware on rented devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS's AUP includes the following wording:

> You may not use, or facilitate or allow others to use, the Services or the AWS Site: ...  to violate the security, integrity, or availability of any user, network, computer or communications system, software application, or network or computing device;

So with regards to installing malware or exposing the devices to live virus or malware payload, the answer is an unequivocal no.

However, I would imagine that as with standard EICAR test strings, you could test file contents for various pattern matches and remain within the bounds of the AUP, ie by including a substring of a particular known malicious payload to test detection. The moment you allowed known malicious code to execute you would be in violation of the AUP, and depending on AWS's inbuilt scanning they may detect and block your access proactively regardless.

So to summarize, the answer is no, you'd need to build your own lab on your own equipment to do testing of this nature.